# Problem with Mediaplayer and 1 mp3

Tags: debian, multimedia

I have a mp4 Video, from that I extract the audio. I use mencoder, mplayer and ffmpeg directly. `ffmpeg -i Videos/Spiele/ZBOF4.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ab 144k /home/alex/Musik/Spielemusik/bof.mp3` The result is always the same. After copying to Media-player `lsusb | grep -i sony
Bus 008 Device 006: ID 054c:085c Sony Corp` The file looses the suffix mp3 and after playing 2 or 3 times it is not longer playable. The format is not supported.  `lsblk -f | grep sdc
sdc

└─sdc1 vfat   WALKMAN         50E2-2700                            /media/alex/WALKMAN`

First I thought the player stuff is broken. But new Videos and mp3's are propper working. So I make a filesystemcheck too. `fsck.vfat /dev/sdc1
fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
/dev/sdc1: 309 files, 79720/220095 clusters` Nothing too complain.

I can't find out where the Problem is. Maybe the Video itself [relevant information I hope](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9510914e6f632ef4eb287beba28d511e) Jessie is the OS.

Comment: what is "1 mp3"?  Can you copy the file after each play and checksum it to see if it's getting corrupted?

Comment: Oh, one mp3. That means it is always the same one

Comment: So you've converted a number of files but only one demonstrates this problem?  What if you force the audio samplerate to 44.1KHz instead of 48.0 KHz?

Comment: Thanks @alex. I changed the sampling rate. I will show the next time if it works permanently.

Comment: @alex can you make your comment an answer so a can except it? It works permanently. In my case it is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the log you provided:

```
Sampling rate : 48.0 KHz
```

This audio sample rate is higher than the usual 44.1 KHz (as used by the Compact Discs) and some players are fussy and don't operate on those higher rates.  Converting with ffmpeg to the lower rate can often fix this.